# How to print JSON data to a Google Sheet using GSpread

Tags: python, json, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have tried every possible fix I can find online, unfortunately, I'm new to this and not sure if I'm getting closer or not.

Ultimately, all I am trying to do is print a JSON feed into a Google Sheet.

GSpread is working (I've appended just number values as a test), but I simply cannot get the JSON feed to print there.

I've gotten it printing to terminal, so I know it's accessible, but writing the loop to append the data becomes the issue.

This is my current script:

```
# import urllib library
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

import gspread


gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('1-1aiGMn2yUWRlh_jnIebcMNs-6phzUNxkktAFH7uY9o')
worksheet = sh.sheet1


# import json
# store the URL in url as
# parameter for urlopen


url = 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random'


# store the response of URL
response = urlopen(url)

# storing the JSON response
# from url in data
data_json = json.loads(response.read())

# print the json response
# print(data_json)
result = []
for key in data_json:
    result.append([key, data_json[key]])
worksheet.update('a1', result)
```

I've hit a complete brick wall - any advice would be greatly appreciated

Update - suggested script with new error:

```
# import urllib library
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

import gspread


gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open_by_key('1-1aiGMn2yUWRlh_jnIebcMNs-6phzUNxkktAFH7uY9o')
worksheet = sh.sheet1


url = 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random'


# store the response of URL
response = urlopen(url)

# storing the JSON response
# from url in data
data_json = json.loads(response.read())

# print the json response
# print(data_json)
result = []
for key in data_json:
    result.append([key, data_json[key] if not isinstance(
        data_json[key], list) else ",".join(map(str, data_json[key]))])
worksheet.update('a1', result)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\Users\AMadle\NBA-JSON-Fetch\PrintToSheetTest.py", line 17, in <module>
    response = urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python\python3.10.5\lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Can confirm it is not a permissions issue, the script below prints the same URL to terminal no problem. Also have no problem writing other data to the sheet:

```
import requests as rq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random'

req = rq.get(url, verify=False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'html.parser')


print(soup)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, I thought that it is required to convert the JSON data to a 2-dimensional array. And, when I saw the value of `data_json`, I noticed that an array is included in the value. I think that it is required to be also considered. I thought that this might be the reason for your issue. When this is reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
result.append([key, data_json[key]])
```

#### To:

```
result.append([key, data_json[key] if not isinstance(data_json[key], list) else ",".join(map(str, data_json[key]))])
```

- In this modification, the array is converted to the string using `join`.

Comment: was very excited to see a potential solution, but a new error is being produced.  I added in the full script along with the new issue in my question. Maybe something small is off there? Thanks for the attempt, this one is killing me!

Comment: @Anthony Madle Thank you for replying. From `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`, I think that this is a new issue. Unfortunately, this issue is not related to my proposed script. I apologize for this. In this case, I think that an error occurs at `response = urlopen(url)`. And, the status code 403 is `The HTTP 403 Forbidden response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.`. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403) Please confirm your URL and whether you can access it again.

Comment: appreciate the persistence here; it's just confusing because the script I now additionally added prints the data to the terminal no problem.  I also confirmed Gspread connection is working separately. Not sure where to go from here unfortunately.

Comment: @Anthony Madle Thank you for replying. I think that your current situation is a new issue. So, first, how about resolving your 1st question? In your 1st question, you wanted to put the JSON object to Spreadsheet. When I accessed your URL, the following value is obtained.

Comment: @Anthony Madle `{"categories":[],"created_at":"2020-01-05 13:42:23.484083","icon_url":"https://assets.chucknorris.host/img/avatar/chuck-norris.png","id":"mJYi6PFzREKPc2q_2RYbPw","updated_at":"2020-01-05 13:42:23.484083","url":"https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/mJYi6PFzREKPc2q_2RYbPw","value":"Darth Vader's lightsaber is a replica of Chuck Norris' shlong."}`

Comment: @Anthony Madle Here, how about testing my proposed script by this value as `data_json`? And, about your new issue, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. Because, your new issue is different from your initial question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: understood, thank you very much. will pose as a new question!